# How to solve "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices" error in Python?

Tags: python, list, class, oop

I have a `student` class that takes attributes and has getter and setter methods and a function called `getTheFirstInClass()`  that takes a list of grades and returns the highest grade.

But the system display this error:

> File "C:\Users\test\student.py", line 30, in 
>   std1.getTheFirstInClass(2.4,4.2,5.6,2.2,1.2) File
>   "C:\Users\test\student.py", line 20, in getTheFirstInClass   if
>   grades[i] > maxValue:
>
> builtins.TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not student

## student.py:

```
class student():
    def __init__(self,name,age, grade):
        self.stdName=name
        self.stdAge = age
        self.stdGrade = grade

    def getName(self):
        print("the student name {}".format(self.stdName))

    def getAge(self):
        print("the student age :{}".format(self.stdAge))

    def getGrade(self):
        print("the student {0}, have a grade {1}".format(self.stdName,self.stdGrade))

    def getTheFirstInClass(*grades:float):
        maxValue = 0
        for i in grades:
            if grades[i] > maxValue:
                maxValue = grades[i]
                i+=1
        return maxValue

std1 = student("georges", 17, 3.4)
std1.getName()
std1.getAge()
std1.getGrade()

std1.getTheFirstInClass(2.4,4.2,5.6,2.2,1.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop iterates over the actual elements of the list, not an index. Just use `i` directly:

```
for i in grades:
    if i > maxValue:
        maxValue = i
```

You also don't need to increment `i`.

Note however that the whole method can be replaced by `max`:

```
return max(grades)
```

Comment: i tried your answer but i got this error :


**builtins.TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'student' and 'int'**

Comment: You forgot to accept the `self` parameter in your method, so it is being treated as the first element of grades.

Comment: Although you should really consider firstly if this should be a method, since it doesn't use any data from the Student object, and secondly if you need it at all given that it's trivially replaced by a call to `max()`.

Comment: so what are the methods that can be included in the student class ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: i have a class called student that i need to create it   with attributes and methods.

so what  are the methods that i can created for this class

Comment: You can create any methods that you like. But it doesn't make sense to create a method that doesn't use any data from the class itself; that sort of thing should be a standalone function, or at the very least a staticmethod.

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `i` as an index here, whereas you have actually defined it as an element in the list `grades`. Try the following:

```
for idx, i in enumerate(grades):
    if grades[idx] > maxValue
```

The preferred and simpler method here would be to avoid using the index altogether and just use the element in the list itself:

```
for grade in grades:
    if grade > maxValue
```

A simplification of your script is given here using `max()`:

```
class student():

    def __init__(self, name, age, grade):
        self.stdName = name
        self.stdAge = age
        self.stdGrade = grade

    def getName(self):
        print("Student name: {}".format(self.stdName))

    def getAge(self):
        print("Student age: {}".format(self.stdAge))

    def getGrade(self):
        print("{0} has a grade of {1}".format(self.stdName,self.stdGrade))

    def getTheFirstInClass(self, grades):
        print("Max grade in the class is " + str(max(grades)))

std1 = student("John Doe", 17, 3.4)
std1.getName()
std1.getAge()
std1.getGrade()
std1.getTheFirstInClass([2.4,4.2,5.6,2.2,1.2])
```

Comment: i tried  this :

`def getTheFirstInClass(*grades:float):
        maxValue = 0
        for i in grades:
            if i > maxValue:
                maxValue = i
                
        return maxValue`

Comment: It if difficult to tell in your comment where a possible error would be, but I would wager it resides in your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getTheFirstInClass(*grades:float):
        maxValue = 0
        for i in grades:
            if grades[i] > maxValue:
                maxValue = grades[i]
                i+=1
        return maxValue
```

In this function you are passing `*grades:float` is a float and while iterating `i` it is float like `2.4,4.2,5.6,2.2,1.2` from the function and It can't be float.

I think you want

```
for i in range(len(grade)):
```